# Browser link to an element in jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

Does anyone know if (using my own serversocket) it's possible to get an element from JDBC (h2? derby?) using a link to put in browser? I need something like "link to database + unique identifier of a record" which would be put in browser so that I could obtain content of the record. I did a lot of googling already but I didn't find anything useful.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Do you mean something like [`REST`](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html?print=yes)?

Comment: You could setup a restful service to do what you are asking. When you hit this URL, http://<your site>/record/12 You can have a restful service query the Database and return the correct DB row in a format of your choice.

Comment: Not directly, JDBC is just an API to connect to a database. Everything else you either need to write yourself, or you need to find a framework that provides this functionality.

Comment: I have to write it all by myself. I woud like to connect in some way the number of the port where I make the SocketServer with the url link to database given, I tried to make it with derby but "Class "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" not found [90086-190]" error occured.